# If an immersion $X$ maps circles into planes then its image $X(\mathbb{D})$ is homeomorphic to the cylinder.

Tags: general-topology, geometry, analysis, differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $X:\left( u,v\right)\in \mathbb{D}\backslash \left\{ 0\right\}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2 \mathbb{%
\longmapsto }\left( x\left( u,v\right) ,y\left( u,v\right) ,z\left(
u,v\right) \right) \in \mathbb{\mathbb{R}}^{3}$ an minimal immersion, where $\mathbb{D=}\left\{ p\in \mathbb{R}^{2};\left\Vert p\right\Vert <1\right\} $ is unitary open disc.

If $X$ maps circles into planes (coordinate function $z$ constant) then $X(\mathbb{D})$ is homeomorphic to cylindric.

I do not know if all these assumptions are necessary, but that's what I have.

Can you help me prove that? I studied geometry and topology a long time ago.

Comment: How can be $z=(u,v)$? z is supposed to belong to $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: $z:\mathbb{D}\rightarrow\mathbb{\mathbb{R}}$ is coordinate function. I edited the post.

Comment: If by $\mathbb{D}$ you mean the unit disk (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_disk) then $0\in \mathbb{D}$ and so what you have written is false: $\mathbb{D}$ is not a subset of $\mathbb {R}^2\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: @pre-kidney. I corrected, thanks.